# PostgreSQL + PostGis + GDAL/Proj/Geos Amazon EC2 image

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

Does anybody have/know any amazon EC2 AMI that has PostgreSQL/PostGIS/GDAL/Proj/Geos installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of - but I was thinking of building one to support the class Paul Ramsey and I teach together. If you want help building it let me know. We are reteaching the class at geoweb and I would like to have it ready for that class. I would also want to put on Java and Geoserver + apache + OpenLayers. We could always branch the image before I put the other stuff on.

I have installed that stack on Ubuntu many times and have the directions. Should we put it on Lucid Beta2, wait 2 weeks for Lucid Final, or go with 9.10?

Comment: Sounds good. Don't think I can be much of a help, I had problems installing the postgis extension (was using CentOS). Maybe just go with Ubuntu 9.10 ?

Comment: When do you need this by? I would prefer to wait the two weeks for 10.04 because it is a long term release and it will have newer versions of the software in the stack

Comment: ok. I wouldn't mind waiting for two weeks. I managed to install PostgreSQL + postgis on Windows 2008 and have been using that. Which Ubuntu AMI did you use to install your stack?

Comment: haven't done it yet - need to learn the AMI stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was using ami-ff17fb96, which runs Ubuntu Karmic.
there is also an EBS volume that has OpenStreetmap data in http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?categoryID=275&externalID=2844

Comment: So guess we should get started - any ideas?